# Trying to call math functions in BATCH Script but getting Random numbers for Result

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The script prompts the user to choose which calculation to perform (call). After I choose an option and calculate the numbers I get random results. Such as 4 + 5 = 27 and 4 * 4 = 0.

```
@echo off
goto :main

:addition
    set /a FNUM1=%~1
    set /a FNUM2=%~2
    set /a RESULT=FNUM + FNUM2
    echo RESULT: %RESULT%
goto :eof

:subtraction
    set /a FNUM1=%~1
    set /a FNUM2=%~2
    set /a RESULT=FNUM - FNUM2
    echo RESULT: %RESULT%
goto :eof

:multiplication
    set /a FNUM1=%~1
    set /a FNUM2=%~2
    set /a RESULT=FNUM * FNUM2
    echo RESULT: %RESULT%
goto :eof

:division
    set /a FNUM1=%~1
    set /a FNUM2=%~2
    set /a RESULT=FNUM / FNUM2
    echo RESULT: %RESULT%
goto :eof

:main
    echo Welcome to the calculator
    echo Please chose one of the following options:
    echo    1 - Addition
    echo    2 - Subtraction
    echo    3 - Multiplication
    echo    4 - Division
    echo    5 - Quit

    set /p CHOICE=
    if "%CHOICE%"=="1" (
        echo YOU CHOSE ADDITION!
        echo Enter first number:
        set /p NUM1=
        echo Added by:
        set /p NUM2=
        call :addition %NUM1% %NUM2%
    )

    if "%CHOICE%"=="2" (
        echo YOU CHOSE SUBTRACTION!
        echo Enter first number:
        set /p NUM1=
        echo Subtracted by:
        set /p NUM2=
        call :subtraction %NUM1% %NUM2%
    )


    if "%CHOICE%"=="3" (
        echo YOU CHOSE MULTIPLICATION!
        echo Enter first number:
        set /p NUM1=
        echo Multiplied by:
        set /p NUM2=
        call :multiplication %NUM1% %NUM2%
    )

    if "%CHOICE%"=="4" (
        echo YOU CHOSE DIVISION!
        echo Enter first number:
        set /p NUM1=
        echo Divided by:
        set /p NUM2=
        call :division %NUM1% %NUM2%
    )

    if "%CHOICE%"=="5" (
        echo Good Bye!
    )
goto :eof
```

I tried to use "/a" for setting FNUM1 and FNUM2, but I still get random results.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The first thing to do is to remove `@echo off` so that you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
set FNUM1=4
set FNUM2=4

set /a RESULT=%FNUM1%*%FNUM2%
echo RESULT: %RESULT%
```

RESULT: 16

```
set /a "RESULT = FNUM1 * FNUM2"
echo RESULT: %RESULT%
```

RESULT: 16

Comment: What are you trying to say here?

Comment: I guess, the point is: "if you are defining `FNUM1` and `FNUM2`, it doesn't make sense to operate with `FNUM` and `FNUM2`"

Comment: The syntax was wrong in his example. Above are the two options he could use instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
:main
echo Welcome to the calculator
echo Please chose one of the following options:
echo    1 - Addition
echo    2 - Subtraction
echo    3 - Multiplication
echo    4 - Division
echo    5 - Quit

set "operation="
set "choice="
set /p CHOICE=
if "%CHOICE%"=="1" set "operation=ADDITION"
if "%CHOICE%"=="2" set "operation=SUBTRACTION"
if "%CHOICE%"=="3" set "operation=MULTIPLICATION"
if "%CHOICE%"=="4" set "operation=DIVISION"
if "%CHOICE%"=="5" (
    echo Good Bye!
)
if not defined operation echo illegal choice&goto main

echo YOU CHOSE %operation%!
echo Enter first number:
set /p NUM1=
echo Second number:
set /p NUM2=
call :%operation% %NUM1% %NUM2%
goto main
goto :eof
```

Your primary issue is can be explained by reading some SO items about `delayed expansion`. In short, within a block (a parenthesised series of lines) any `%var%` is replaced by the value of `var` at the time the block is encountered, so changing `num?` within the block does not alter the values passed to the subroutine - it is `num?` as it was when the execution of the block *began*.

Mods: set `choice` to *nothing* before executing a `set/p` because if simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pushed, the variable will not become *empty*, but *unchanged*

establish a new variable, `operation` and set it to *nothing*

depending on the choice made (perhaps you should try `choice /?` from the prompt for a better method) set `operation` to the appropriate value.

Since each entry produced (nearly) the same text, enter the values, then perform the calculation.

Perhaps you may want to put something like

```
echo %1 ? %2=%result%
```

in each subroutine, OR change `operation` within the subroutine to `+`, `-` etc. and in the main routine, after the `call :%operation%...` (which chooses the subroutine to run) try

echo %num1% %operation% %num2%=%result%

which should fill in `operation` as set by the routine ":*oldvalueofoperation*"

Comment: First, I had a mistake in my code I had just FNUM instead of FNUM1 in my functions.
Second, I used access_granted's suggestion "set /a "RESULT = FNUM1 * FNUM2"
Finally, I used your method for ":main".
I had to do all these steps before the script would function properly.